# Путь к файлу как ссылка на файл в интернете

Tags: python

Возможно ли в Python открытие какого-либо файла из интернета, например из GitHub'а?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под открытием?

Comment: [Напишите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1307264/edit) подробнее, какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить? Какого вида ваша ссылка? Что вы называете "открытием" файла?

Answer (score 1):

URL не является путём до файла. Чтобы загрузить файл по ссылке через HTTP нужно выполнить HTTP-запрос. Используйте библиотеку requests.
Здесь url - это ссылочка на файл.
Далее, уже в зависимости от содержимого, сохранить в файл.

```
# Свой урл помести сюда
url = 'www.my_site.ru/my_file.txt'
# HTTP get-запрос
response = requests.get(url)

# Если запрос прошёл успешно
if response.status_code == 200:
  # достаём содержимое, которое вернул запрос
  content = response.content
  # путь куда сохранить файл
  file_path = 'c:/my_file.txt'
  # открыли файл на запись
  f = open(my_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
  # записали
  f.write(content)
  f.flush()
  f.close()

else: 
  print('Ошибка запроса. Статус',response.status_code)
```

Вероятно, как-то так должно происходить.